# wordpress preview demo plugin

Tags: wordpress, themes, preview

I've started seeing on wordpress theme sites with the ability to preview a theme on the same page, I've tried searching for the plugin but I can't find any - I'm assuming its an iframe but I could be mistaken. Has anyone come across this before and whats the solution as I want to be able to create this for myself?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Theme Test Drive plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/).

Once activated, you should be able to combine the preview URLs `(http://www.myblog.com/?theme=Default)` with iframes and/or whatever lightbox solution you prefer.